# Is there any way of getting the parent from the child nsArraycontroller?

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

using cocoa bindings, i have bound to the following:

ChildArrayController

```
ContentSet
bindto: ParentArrayController
controllerkey: selection
modelkeypath: children
```

Is there any way of getting the parent from the child controller?

`[childArrayController arrangedObjects]` is the children.

`[childArrayController selectedObjects]` is the selected children.

`[childArrayController content]` is an array

[childArrayController selection] is a proxy for the selected child.

I want to do something like `id parent = [childArrayController xxx];`

Comment: Can you please explain it more. what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I agree, please explain more about what you're trying to do. Maybe there is an other solution for your problem? Otherwise try subclassing.